# Is it possible to make a local notification not appear in the history if the app is in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

Can't find any way to do this, but as I saw many apps can do this. It's very often I noticed in skype app, when in lock screen I see notification but on notification centre, notifications is not appear in the history. Vice versa, not see any notification on lock screen but I see them in notification centre.

If app state is on a foreground, yes I can prevent them by this code in AppDelegate file:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
    }
}
```

But this method called when user interaction with notification in background, and at this time notification is already in centre.

So any suggestions? Thx.

Comment: are you want generate a local notification  when app is killed or background ?

Comment: @balkaransingh, no. user lock device, app fine work in background, after some action, app generate local notification, then fired it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like,

```
  if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
}

//or

if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

in same `didReceiveLocalNotification` method!!

Comment: `didReceiveLocalNotification:` don't called when app in background! Only after user slide to open on this notification

Comment: It's don't have any sense, delegate method don't called at this moment

Comment: yes, I know, but this is not needed solution. I don't understand how apps like skype use this? In settings app, this function is enable.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to test the approach and decided to cancel the `UILocalNotification` with a help of a `dispatch_after`. Here is the code:

```
UILocalNotification *theLocalNotification = [UILocalNotification new];
theLocalNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:10 sinceDate:[NSDate new]];
theLocalNotification.alertBody = @"test";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:theLocalNotification];
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(12 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
               {
                   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:theLocalNotification];
               });

// the  below lines are needed so that `dispatch_after` runs when app is in background
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:5];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
```

It does successfully cancel the `UILocalNotification`, however, it turns out that `cancelLocalNotification:` method removes the notification from **both** lock screen **and** history screen. Therefore, we are not even looking in the right direction, there should be some other way of doing the thing.